# Azure Data Factory - REST Linked Service - OAuth2 Client Credentials

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

From Azure Data Factory, I'm trying to connect to a REST service that requires an access token (OAuth2).
Tried in Postman with the client credentials flow (client_id/client_secret) and it works fine:

1. Calling the token endpoint to get an access_token
2. Use the token in a subsequent request to retrieve data.

I configured the linked service like that as It supposed to support the OAuth2 client credentials flow:

[image]

But when testing the connection, it fails with this message:

```
The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret'.
```

I don't really understand why the client_secret is not added in the request body as it is a client credentials flow.

Not sure if I'm missing some configuration ?
For the moment, I'm using Web Activity as a workaround.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error may occurred because `Allow public client flows` is disabled for the application registered in Azure AD.

Enabling it may fixed the issue.

Refer -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services?tabs=data-factory

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token?tabs=python#username-and-password

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer butthis did not do the trick. Will try to see if I can enable some debugging to see what data factory is trying to send.